# Import module from nested directories in Elm?

Tags: python, import, elm, multi-module

If I have a directory structure like this:

```
src
 ├── Commands.elm
 ├── Decoders.elm
 ├── Main.elm
 ├── Messages.elm
 ├── Models.elm
 ├── Page
 │   ├── Cats
 │   │   ├── Main.elm
 │   │   ├── Style.elm
 │   │   └── ...
 │   ├── Pieces
 │   │   ├── Main.elm
 │   │   ├── Style.elm
 │   │   └── ...
 │   └── Players
 │       ├── Main.elm
 │       ├── Style.elm
 │       └── ...
 ├── Routing.elm
 ├── Style
 │   ├── Index.elm
 │   ├── MainCss.elm
 │   └── Main.elm
 ├── Update.elm
 └── View.elm
```

I found some examples that show how to import a module from a directory, but I couldn't find an example on how to import a module from a sub-driectory.
For example, how do I import `Page/Cats/Main.elm` in `View.elm`?

In Python I would put a `__init__.py` into each nested directory to turn them into *packages* which would allow me to reach the modules in them like this `from Page import Cats` or like this `from Page.Cats import Main`. Is there a similar concept in Elm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `src` is in `source-directories` in `elm-package.json`, just make sure the module name in that file matches the path, i.e. `Page.Cats.Main`:

```
module Page.Cats.Main exposing (add)

add x y = x + y
```

and then import that in `View.elm`:

```
import Page.Cats.Main

-- You can now call functions defined in that module like this:
-- Page.Cats.Main.add 1 2
```

Comment: This solved it! I wasn't aware that you have to mirror the directory structure when exposing modules. Thanks for your fast reply!

Comment: Yep, the module name must match the path of the file. That's how the Elm compiler looks up a module's file for each `import`.